# Why do languages differ about when `super` must be called in a constructor?

Tags: object-oriented, constructors

Many languages require you to call `super` before setting your own properties, like in TypeScript:

```typescript
class Base {
  public x: number;

  constructor(x: number) {
    this.x = x;
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  public y: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    // Error to use `this` here, before the `super` call

    super(x);

    this.y = y; // OK (and in fact required)
  }
}
```

However, Swift reverses this:

```swift
class Base {
  var x: Int

  init(x: Int) {
    self.x = x
  }
}

class Derived: Base {
  var y: Int

  init(x: Int, y: Int) {
    self.y = y // Error to NOT do this here

    super.init(x: x)
  }
}
```

What difference does it make, and why would a language enforce one or the other?

Answer (score 7):

There is a specific problem that this is trying to solve, which is to prevent code from outside of the constructor from observing an uninitialised object. The issue is that constructors are allowed to call methods on the same class, and those methods aren't supposed to observe an uninitialised object; but those methods can be overridden by subclasses.

Consider the following in Typescript: ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQE4FMwBMD2AdiAJ7QBmeeAXNAQK4C2ARpugNwprCEQAu6dYLzzoAFAEpEnNGl4ALAJYQAdBTzQAvNACsHGTPlLlIPAHMJetAF9p0E+fE0AbngU4p+rjzwhMxs6IABmqa0AAkCIYqalaB4paoNjZIoJAwAELQmAAevJgEODDwyDJYuIQk0Exg6DT0zKwJ0NwEfAJCIhIentAQdAAOrBa2Booq1eihAGxNNjL2Es6u7iU9LRA+fgvBlKERUaqUVgA0VTV7kWPKE7HxtklISASYAO7Q6RJIQA))

```typescript
class A {
    readonly foo: number;
    constructor() {
        this.foo = 5;
        this.log();
    }
    log(): void {
        console.log(`foo = ${this.foo}`);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    readonly bar: number;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.bar = 6;
    }
    log(): void {
        console.log(`foo = ${this.foo}, bar = ${this.bar}`);
    }
}

new B()
// foo = 5, bar = undefined
```

In this example, the `log` method from class `B` is invoked before the assignment `this.bar = 6;` in `B`'s constructor, so the method is able to observe an uninitialised object. This means Typescript's rule ─ that `super()` must be called before any use of `this` ─ does not actually solve the problem. Well, it solves part of the problem, but not all of it: it at least means you can't call `this.log();` in `B`'s constructor before the `super();` call.

Java has a stricter version of the same rule: `super();` must be the first thing in the subclass's constructor. But Java's rule has the same problem. (The equivalent Java code will print `0` instead of `undefined`.)

So Swift's rule ─ that subclass fields must be initialised before calling `super.init();`, and `super.init();` must be called before any *other* use of `self` ─ is better, in the sense that it protects against an uninitialised field being observed outside of the constructor in the class that declares that field.

Comment: In languages that differentiate virtual and final methods, this could be mitigated by disallowing virtual methods in the ctor, right?

Comment: @Bbrk24: C++ has another approach - base classes are always initialized first, and calls to virtuals are allowed, but they don't dispatch virtually - it is as if the more derived types don't exist while a base constructor is running (same for destructors). Better explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/962298/635608

Comment: @Bbrk24 Yes, at the cost of expressiveness. I think besides backwards compatibility, the reason Java and Typescript allow this is mainly because the language is more useful if you can call methods from constructors, and if that means observing a default initial value (`0`, `null`, `undefined`, etc.) by accident occasionally then that's worth it. It at least doesn't violate memory safety, and there are a few other ways in Java to sneakily observe fields before they are initialised.

Comment: @Mat I think that should be an answer!

Answer (score 1):

### Computation symmetry on constructors

Say, you have two classes, `MultipleOfTwo` and `MultipleOfFour`. The construct of MultipleOfTwo accepts a number and either succeeds or fails.

```
def MultipleOfTwo
{
  def __construct( n )
  {
    if ( n % 2 != 0 ) throw new Error();
    this.Number = n;
  }
}
```

But your MultipleOfFour *cannot* have the same functionality:

```
def MultipleOfFour
{
  def __construct( n )
  {
    this = super(n);                     // First construct Mo2
    if ( n % 4 != 0 ) throw new Error(); // then fails
    // ...
  }
}
```

Languages that force `super` as the first element on a derived class (Java, C#) also force you to create "factories" around this limitation, in an artificial way of separating concerns that in turn creates *a lot* of duplicating code.

Comment: Swift and TypeScript mitigate this to an extent by only imposing restrictions on uses of `self`/`this`, and allowing other computations to go wherever. Still, this is a fair point against the way Java does it.